# How to make an image of the current rendered map (mapbox-android)?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Is it possible to make a png or data-url of the current view on the map?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply save the current map as a `.png`, by taking a screenshot (`MapboxMap#snapshot`) after the map has loaded.

Ensure you've got the appropriate `build.gradle` dependency:

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'){
    transitive = true
}
```

Code for capturing the map:

```
private void captureScreen() {

    mMapBoxMap.snapshot(new MapboxMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            ImageView snapshotView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.);
            snapshotView.setImageBitmap(snapshot);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This won't work as the map referred in the OP is a SurfaceView (when creating images as shown in this answer, you will get a black image without a map)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of getting a map bitmap:

- from an existing map with `MapboxMap#snapshot(SnapshotReadyCallback)`
- without an existing map using the `MapSnapshotter.java` class and the related options class.